# Chrooted sftp gives "Permission denied" error

Tags: centos, sftp

I have configured sshd_conf on my centos box as below:

```
Match group pilots
ChrootDirectory /home/pilots
ForceCommand internal-sftp
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

and the directory /home/pilots like this:

```
# ls -al /home/pilots
total 12
drwxr-x---. 3 root pilots 4096 Mar 10 14:20 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root root     4096 Mar 10 14:10 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root pilots 4096 Mar 10 15:21 data
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root        0 Mar 10 14:20 topLevel
#
```

If I sftp in as a user in the pilots group WITHOUT the ChrootDirectory Directive enabled, I can cd to the /home/pilots folder (or a subdirectory thereof) and do a ls or get without difficulty. However, if I enable the ChrootDirectory directive, while I can still sftp in, and can cd to data, I can not do a ls or get in either directory. Trying ls, for example, gives a `remote readdir("/"): Permission denied` error, and trying to get topLevel gives `File "/topLevel" not found`. I was thinking maybe I wasn't in the directory I was expecting, but the ability to cd data would appear to indicate the chroot did work as intended. What might I be doing wrong?

Couple of potentially important notes:

- The users in question exist on a remote LDAP server, accessed via sssd
- Access control must be by group, as many users will need read access to this same folder. Thus the ownership remaining root.

Edit: I just noticed this in the messages log:

```
type=1400 audit(1394494944.504:50): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=22758 comm="sshd" name="pilots" dev=dm-0 ino=400504 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:chroot_user_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

So there's a record of the denial. Still doesn't tell me why though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution on [this page](http://cassjohnston.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/selinux-and-chrooted-sftp/). To summarize, after configuring sftp as per the above configuration, the following two commands needed to be run to allow access with SELinux enabled:

```
setsebool -P ssh_chroot_rw_homedirs on
restorecon -R /home/$USERNAME
```

In this case, the second command would be restorecon -R /home/pilots. After this, sftp works as expected, even when chrooted, without having to disable SELinux completely.

Comment: If you want to access directories which are not homedirs, you can try `setsebool ssh_chroot_full_access on` or `setsebool ssh_chroot_manage_apache_content on` (use `getsebool -a` to find out what else is out there).